# How to remove/hide $RECYCLE.BIN and System Volume Information folders?

Tags: dual-boot, permanent-delete

I am running dual boot (Ubuntu 16.10 and Windows 10). When I boot into Ubuntu, I always see the 2 folders `$RECYCLE.BIN` and `System Volume Information`. Besides, in one drive I see a file named `pagefile.sys`. I delete them all, but every time I boot into Ubuntu, they appear again.

Can anyone show me how to permanently delete them, or at least hide them because I find them annoying. Thanks

Comment: Those are Windows system files, not a good idea to delete them.

Comment: I deleted them, then booted into Windows. Everything works normally. Then I booted into Ubuntu, they appeared again. Can you suggest any solutions, just to hide them in Ubuntu because I don't want to see them.

Comment: An immediate  solution would be not to share partitions with Windows. I am not quite sure it's worth the trouble, but that's for you to decide.

Comment: Thank you. But I have to switch back and forth between the 2 operating systems from time to time, so I need the common storage that both OS can access. Hope someone can invent something just to hide these annoying stuff.

Comment: ...or may be you'll just get used to it. :~) How bad can it really be?

Comment: yeah, I think I'll have to learn to live with them for a while :)

Comment: You should be able to get rid of `pagefile.sys`. I am dual-booting with an old Windows XP and in XP I managed to create a separate partition for the page-file and only this partition will be used for the page-file. How to do that in Windows 10 I am over-asked, you could place a question about this at [superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 13):

Create a text file `.hidden` on your hard drive, and add folders you wish to hide, like this:

```
found.000
$RECYCLE.BIN
RECYCLER
System Volume Information
pagefile.sys
```

Comment: simple and works perfectly - why is this not accepted?

Comment: Is there a man page for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

The NTFS-3G file system driver has mount options that let you show/hide files with the "system" or "hidden" file attributes. Windows uses these flags to hide files in its file manager by default. The mount options are

- `show_sys_files` (the default is to *hide* them) and
- `hide_hid_files` (the default is to *show* them)

respectively.

The [NTFS-3G manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/mount.ntfs.8.html) says about them:

> **`show_sys_files`** – Show  the metafiles in directory listings. Otherwise the default behaviour is to hide the metafiles, which are special files used to  store the NTFS structure. Please note that even when this option is specified, `$MFT` may not be visible due to a glibc bug. Furthermore, irrespectively of `show_sys_files`, all files are accessible by name, for example you can always do `ls  -l '$UpCase'`.
>
> **`hide_hid_files`** – Hide the hidden files and directories in directory listings, the hidden files and directories being the ones whose NTFS attribute have the hidden flag set. The hidden files will not be selected when using wildcards in commands, but all files and directories remain accessible by full name, for example you can always display the Windows trash bin directory by: `ls -ld '$RECYCLE.BIN'`.